# What does "Reviews Completed" status mean in Springer?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to one of the Springer Journals through Editorial Manager almost 5 months back. The status changed from Editor Assigned to Under Review and now it is showing "Reviews Completed" since past five days. Can anybody suggest what does it actually mean and is there any other stage before the decision is made? 
Does it give any indication about the reviewers **not rejecting** my submission?

Comment: It means: chill out and stop torturing the "refresh" button.

Comment: Related: [On Elsevier, does “required reviews completed” mean good news or bad?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/45375/10643)

Answer (score 5):

It's waiting for the editor to read the reviews and make a decision. This could mean one of the following: 'reject', 'submit as new', 'major revision, 'minor revision' or 'accept' (Depending on the journal, options may change).

Any decision above 'major revision' is good, meaning you get a chance to improve the paper and hopefully get to full accept.  Of course the paper can still be rejected at any stage until it is fully accepted.

Best of luck!

Comment: Any time frame for this status?

Comment: Up to the editor.. who is usually very busy and would be about the last thing he/she would do.....so be patient.